# submit form via jquery FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload a file using jquery. Here's the form:

```
<form id="upload_data" class="project" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

<select id="project_id" name="project_id">
   <option value="1">1</option> 
   <option value="2">2</option> 
</select>

 <input  type="file" id="data" name="data" />

<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="12" required>

<button type="submit" id="ajax" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's the jquery part:

```
$('#upload_data').submit( function( e ) {

        var form = $('form');
        var formData = new FormData();

                $.each($(':input', form ), function(i, fileds){
                   formData.append($(fileds).attr('name'), $(fileds).val());
               });

                $.each($('input[type=file]',form )[0].files, function (i, file) {
                   formData.append(file.name, file);
               });

$.ajax( {
      url: '../controllers/process.php',
      type: 'POST',
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);

        }
    } );

    });
```

The problem is that I am getting empty post values in process.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['project_id']) AND isset($_POST['user_id'])){
   //process 
}else{
echo 'No post data';
}
```

It always return 'No post data' (But in console, I can see that data has been posted but it's not the case in server.). What am I missing here?

Comment: Your code seems fine, although there's no `enctype` property, so you can remove that, and you can shorten the `FormData` object population by just doing `var formData = new FormData(form[0]);` and removing the `$.each()` calls. To check your AJAX logic, set a `action` on the `<form>` element and submit it normally to see if your PHP receives data that way

Comment: Probably you are looking at wrong variable, since you are posting a file, you won't find it in $_post.. check $_FILES

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Try: formData.append('file', file, file.name);

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan setting the action works but not the ajax way.

Comment: @Gunnrryy i've var_dump both but the same output 0.

Comment: @DanielO. same problem

Comment: This code works for me: https://gist.github.com/odan/fd434f17667c42c482df3507d6fc8917

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit functions from Ajax Form Plugin or the jQuery serialize function.

[jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

and

[How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you are appending a file to formData

```
formData.append(file.name, file);
```

You need to use this version of the method as per MDN docs

```
formData.append(name, value, filename);
```

That will allow you to present a fieldname, file data, and file name

Also you might consider just submiting the form itself without the need for using formData

Comment: I've also tried these. But server script is not getting all post data.

Comment: `You need to use this version of the method as per MDN docs` That's not true. If you read the docs you'll see that the last parameter is optional

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your reply. The problem was about `max_upload_filesize` and `post_max_size`. I increased the values for these options and now it's working. Thanks.